# How to make Audio work dynamically and separately like DynamicImage?

Tags: dynamic, visualization, customization, sound

In *Mathematica*, there is a new function `DynamicImage` that can enlarge or drag picture dynamically.

So, is there a function `DynamicAudio` that acts like `DynamicImage`?
In *Adobe Audition*, there is a line indicating which part is playing.

[image]

Audio file:

```
a = AudioChannelMix[#, "Mono"] &@ExampleData[{"Audio","ChurchBell"},"Audio"];
```

So I define a function can plot Audio dynamicly.

```
DynamicAudioPlot[a_?AudioQ, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{mngr = Audio`Internals`GetAudioManager[Audio`AudioInformation[a, "AudioID"]], yrange, p = AudioPlot[a, opts]},
 yrange = Options[p, PlotRange][[1, 2, 2]]; 
 AppendTo[p[[2]], Epilog -> 
  Line[{{Dynamic@Audio`AudioDump`getGUIInfo[mngr, "AudioPosition"],yrange[[1]]}, 
        {Dynamic@Audio`AudioDump`getGUIInfo[mngr, "AudioPosition"],yrange[[2]]}}]];
 Audio`Internals`Execute[mngr, "Play"]; p]

DynamicAudioPlot[a, PlotTheme -> "Minimal", AspectRatio -> 1/5]
```

[image]

Or plot the DynamicSpectrogram of audio object

```
DynamicSpectrogram[a_Audio, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{mngr = 
    Audio`Internals`GetAudioManager[Audio`AudioInformation[a, "AudioID"]], yrange, 
    p = Spectrogram[a, opts]}, 
    yrange = AbsoluteOptions[p, PlotRange][[1, 2, 2]];
    AppendTo[p, Epilog -> Line[{{Dynamic@Audio`AudioDump`getGUIInfo[mngr, "AudioPosition"], yrange[[1]]}, {Dynamic@Audio`AudioDump`getGUIInfo[mngr, "AudioPosition"], yrange[[2]]}}]];
    Audio`Internals`Execute[mngr, "Play"]; p]
DynamicSpectrogram[a]
```

[image]

Or plot the attribute of audio dynamically.

```
DynamicAudioAttributePlot[a_?AudioQ, prop_String, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{
 mngr = Audio`Internals`GetAudioManager[Audio`AudioInformation[a, "AudioID"]], yrange, 
 p = ListLinePlot[AudioLocalMeasurements[a, prop], opts]},
 yrange = Options[p, PlotRange][[1, 2, 2]]; 
 AppendTo[p[[2]], 
 Epilog -> Line[{{Dynamic@Audio`AudioDump`getGUIInfo[mngr, "AudioPosition"], yrange[[1]]}, 
                 {Dynamic@Audio`AudioDump`getGUIInfo[mngr, "AudioPosition"], yrange[[2]]}}]];
 Audio`Internals`Execute[mngr, "Play"]; p]

DynamicAudioAttributePlot[a, "MFCC", PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image]

But it has problem that the plot of dynamic Audio not work separately.
So how to fix it?
[image]

***Ps:***
I find crucial reason of the problem is `Audio`AudioInformation`.

```
a = AudioChannelMix[#, "Mono"] &@ExampleData[{"Audio", "ChurchBell"}, "Audio"]

Audio`AudioInformation[a, "AudioID"] == Audio`AudioInformation[a, "AudioID"](*True*)
Audio`AudioInformation[...dialog box..., "AudioID"] ==Audio`AudioInformation[...dialog box..., "AudioID"](*Flase*)
```

[image]

You can see when directly drag the ...dialog box... to that place.Audio object become independent.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Here is my modest attempt:

```
dynamicAudio[aud_Audio, opts___] :=
       With[{len = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Duration[aud], "Seconds"]]},
            DynamicModule[{pts = {{0., 0.}, {len, 0.}}}, 
                          Panel[Column[{LocatorPane[Dynamic[pts,
                                (pts = Transpose[{Sort[#[[All, 1]], LessEqual],
                                                  {0., 0.}}];) &], 
                          AudioPlot[aud, Epilog -> {Opacity[1/2, LightRed], 
                                         Rectangle[Dynamic[Scaled[{0, -1}, pts[[1]]]], 
                                                   Dynamic[Scaled[{0, 1}, pts[[2]]]]]},
                                    opts], Appearance -> None], 
                          Item[Button["\[FilledRightTriangle]", 
                               EmitSound[Sound`AudioToSound[AudioTrim[aud,
                                         pts[[All, 1]]]]], 
                                      ImageSize -> Medium, Method -> "Queued"], 
                               Alignment -> Right]}]], SaveDefinitions -> True]]
```

An example:

```
ps = ExampleData[{"Sound", "PianoScale"}, "Audio"];
dynamicAudio[ps, Background -> Black, FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {None, All}},
             PlotStyle -> Green]
```

[image: dynamicAudio example]